# how do you specify an (Un)Exported Symbols file when building a macos framework with cmake?

Tags: macos, cmake

How do you specify an (Un)Exported Symbols file when building a macos framework with cmake?  I don't see any way to call the linker with a `-unexported_symbols_list` flag.  I would assume that's it's a setting in a block like this, but I don't see the relevant setting in the cmake doc:

```
set_target_properties(dynamicFramework PROPERTIES
  FRAMEWORK TRUE
  FRAMEWORK_VERSION C
  MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.cmake.dynamicFramework
  MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST Info.plist
  # "current version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
  VERSION 16.4.0
  # "compatibility version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
  SOVERSION 1.0.0
  PUBLIC_HEADER dynamicFramework.h
  XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
)
```

Comment: You may specify per-linker flags with `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - sure, but that's nasty.  It seemed obvious to me that there had to be a way to do it in the PROPERTIES, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Do not expect CMake developers tend to create properties for **every** compiler/linker option.